# How to pass navigator reference to nested child components?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I want to make navigation drawer list item clickable, in that scenario i want navigator object to navigate another scene. How can i pass navigator reference there from main component to child component? My child components of Main components are ListView and ListItems. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to pass it down just like any other prop. I'm assuming you're passing `navigator` down to the routed component...

```js
<Navigator
  ref='Navigator'
  renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
             let RoutedComponent = route.component
             return (
               <RoutedComponent navigator={navigator} {...route.props}/>
             )
  }}
/>
```

If so, in the `RoutedComponent` just pass the navigator down to it's child components through props.

```
<MyChildComponent navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
```

Comment: can we pass reference to deep in many nested child components? I had done as mentioned you above but cannot get right result.

Comment: Yes, the reference can continue being passed as deep as you want. Something is probably getting lost in translation. Can you post some example code? Also, try debugging in Chrome and inspecting the value of `this.props` where you want to access the navigator to see what's being set.

Comment: Ok i will try again and thanks for suggestion. If problem occurs i will surely comment you here. Thanks again.

Comment: I was hoping you could do something that would use the getChildContext() similar to how the `<Provider/>` component does in `react-redux` in order to automatically pass the navigator prop down through the children.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store

Comment: You could set it up like that.. There could be libraries now though that would do that for you, but it wouldn't be too hard to do it yourself.